# Print the formula used to describe the addition of two numbers

Tags: java, addition

I am stuck in the [U of Helsinki Java MOOC](https://java-programming.mooc.fi/part-1/5-calculating):

> Create a program that can be used to add two integers together. In the beginning, the user is asked to give two integers that are to be summed. The program then prints the formula that describes the addition of the numbers.
>
> Example output:
>
> ```
> Give the first number:
> 5
> Give the second number:
> 4
> 5 + 4 = 9
> ```

I am trying to get the system to print " "first" + "second" is "result". For some reason I am stumped on this otherwise easy question. My code is always throwing an error. What am I doing wrong in the last line?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AdditionFormula {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    // write your program here
    System.out.println("Give the first number: ");
    int first = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
    
    System.out.println("Give the second number: ");
    int second = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
    
    //System.out.println("first" " + " Integer.valueOf(first) + Integer.valueOf(second));
    System.out.println(first + " + " + second " = " + (first + second));
}
```

Comment: 1. Use `Integer.parseInt` instead of `Integer.valueOf` to avoid boxing overhead. 2. It's simply a typo. 3. The error message tells you what the problem is.

Comment: Are these basically synonymous? The tutorial hasn't introduced the parseInt one, but I can try it.

Comment: They do exactly the same (if I recall correctly, `valueOf` calls `parseInt` internally), but `valueOf` returns an `Integer` object, whereas `parseInt` returns an `int`.

Comment: This looks like a premature micro-optimization, which would be otherwise [discouraged](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/), but the speed advantage of avoiding autoboxing/unboxing can be significant in some cases.

Comment: Thank you, sorry. There is a 20 minute minimum I needed to wait before I could accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided does not compile

Change to

```
System.out.println(first + " + " + second + " = " + (first + second));
```